# getting fatal: attempt to use a scalar value as array error while creating join between two files

Tags: awk

I am creating a full outer join between two files and to do so, I am using awk to store both the files records in separate array and then print them later by using two for loops.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}{x=1;b[x]=$0;x=x+1} END{for(i in b[i]){for (j in a[j]) print b[i] "\t" a[j] "" }}' transpose.txt rows.txt
```

The error I get by is this part

```
END{for(i in b[i]){for (j in a[j]) print b[i] "\t" a[j] "" }}
```

I tried running the code without this part, print just a[1] and b[1]. It is able to do so. But when I put two for loops there to print the full outer join of two. I get this array os using scalar value as array! What am I doing wrong here?
The full error I get is

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=rows.txt FNR=176) fatal: attempt to use a scalar value as array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully sure about your requirement, tried to fix your code. Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{b[FNR]=$0} END{for(i in b){for (j in a) print b[i] "\t" a[j] }}' transpose.txt rows.txt
```

Comment: this actually works. Thanks. So apparently i in b [i] was wrong way. Your fixed code works fine.

Comment: @noobCoder, why because `b[i]` represents value of `b` which we don't want, we need it to traverse through an array not through array's values, you could select this answer as correct one too, cheers.